# Handling JavaFX event in function key

Tags: java, javafx

How can I add a function key (i.e. the <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> keys) for shortcut key in JavaFX? 
**I use save button. I don’t need to click save button and it make easy to system**

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Button, let's say `saveButton` and it is in Scene `scene` then you can set accelerator(shortcut key) to button as following:

```
Button saveButton = new Button("save");
scene.getAccelerators().put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F1), saveButton::fire);
```

`KeyCodeCombination` in above code is used to set accelerators to javaFX contols and It takes, as argument, `KeyCode` e.g. `KeyCode.K`, `KeyCode.F3` etc. and/or `KeyCombination` like `KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN` etc.

and if you are using MenuItem let's say `saveMenu` then you can set accelerator(shortcut key) to it as following:

```
MenuItem saveMenu = new MenuItem("save");
saveMenu.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.F1));
```